# How to put a limit in Pandas to the number of rows read from a 'feather' file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, hdf5, feather

I have a `feather` datafile that weights approximately 300 MB, name it `df.ftr`. I can read it with Pandas using the following command:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_feather('df.ftr')
```

However, this dataset contains over 21 million rows and its size overflows my local computer's memory. What I would like to do is to read only the first 1 million rows.

If it were an `df.h5` file, I would read it by using the `stop` argument of the `read_hdf` method (documentation available [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_hdf.html)):

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_hdf('df.h5', 'table', stop=1000000)
```

However, after checking the [read_feather()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_feather.html) documentation, there is no argument which seems to be able to produce the same effect.

How can it be done?